# Force specific column of specific sheet to be percentage with 2 decimal places

Tags: excel, vba

Any idea how to force with VBA the column "B" of sheet called "extra" to have format of percentage with 2 decimal places? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "%#0.00"` I believe.

Comment: I put the % on the wrong side. `Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "#0.00%"`

Comment: How to put what you wrote above in a command to point to a specific sheet? thanks

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "#0.00%"`

Comment: thanks! works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

In the code sheet for "extra" , place this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Columns("B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Intersect(Columns("B"), Target).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would need sth to run after the fields be placed.. I tried your method but didnt work

Comment: As per your question, to 'force' ... column B ... to have format of % in 2 decimals. Hence the code is about it, every time when changes are made to the sheet "extra", the code runs automatically and change all numbers in column B to 0.00%. Most importantly you need to put the code into the code page of the sheet, not a module (which generally require manual running).